# Why IE Shows .png image rough in compare to other browser?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using a .png file in my menu which appear well and good in other browsers with smooth edge while it appear with rough edge in IE. PLease help me to solve why IE treat .png in different way in compare to other browsers.

```
  <li>

               <a href="" onclick="window.open('http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g1131922-d4550301-Reviews-Camp_X_Terra_Ranichauri_by_Nature_Connect_Outdoors_Pvt_Ltd-New_Tehri_Uttarakhand.html')" onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/trip.jpg', 'test')">

              <img  onMouseOver="changeBgImage('images/trip.jpg', 'test')" src="images/tripadvisor.png" alt="Trip Advisor" title="Trip Advisor" width="40"  height="40"  />

              </a>

              </li>
```

Comment: In which IE Versions?

Comment: I am using IE 9 and my BOSS using IE 11

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web graphic design.

Answer (score 1):

Try in css:

```
img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
```

MS are rendering image with own lib (gdi I think) and try to speed things up with a fast filter

Comment: I have used this one   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
     src='image.png', sizingMethod='scale'); but not working

Comment: Not tested: I don't have a windows box anymore

Comment: asking for ie 6 perticularly for online demo. while we are using 9 and 11